# C++ Intellisense doesn't work (not even Ctrl+Space), no function name, no parameter list, nothing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I have recently install the C++ in order to re-learn the language (have done some small project on it). One thing that really annoys me is that the auto-complete function when implementation doesn't work anymore.

More specifically the auto-completing of the parameters and function name. I have already declared my class and functions in respective headers. Though my memory is a bit hazy, I remember back in 2008, once you enter the name in the cpp file, it will automatically give you a dropdown box for the respective parameters.

Then I have searched for forums and pages for possible solution and was informed that the intellisense feature was removed from the C++ environment in the new VS 2010 (why?). But one can retrieve the parameter list by:
(1) checking the 'Tool -> Text Editor -> C++ -> Autolist Members" and also in the advanced tab to see if the feature has been disabled.
(2) to use Ctrl-Space while completing the statement.

I have tried both of these and they don't work (and I have read some the forums that the ctrl+space should at least work in some degree). Declaration should be correct because when I am defining the function and right-click and name to "Go to Declaration" it will highlight the declaration in the header file (where the whole parameter list is provided).
And the Ctrl+J would show me that indeed VS recognize the function declaration.

I would like to not use the 3rd party software such as (visual assist X), but I am running out of options.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Do you have MSSQL 2008 R2 installed?  This interferes with intellisense in VS.Net 2010 apparently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are not targeting the .NET framework (compiler option `/clr` )
Otherwise it should work for all **native** C++ programs